# sns pairplot diagonal distribution

Tags: python, deep-learning, seaborn, data-visualization

I was trying to see the output of a neural network on a binary classification using pairplot. I stored the logits, yhats and the labels in a dataframe. Then i used:

```
sns.pairplot(df, hue = 'yhat')
```

and i got:

[image]

The problems is in the first and second rows diagonals, where there is an intersection between distributions. As I know, they should be completely non-overlapping.
To be sure, I tried the problem with `matplotlib hist` function too. The results is as expected:

[image]

I do not know if it is a bug in sns, or it is kind of representation or something else.

Comment: You can use `sns.pairplot(..., diag_kind="hist")` to get histograms on the diagonal. A kde smooths out the distribution using a gaussian kernel, which can cause overlaps as well as values outside the valid range.

Comment: @JohanC, there is also overlapping. It is possibly because of the bin size, which apparently can not be set.

Comment: The parameters for the diagonal plot are set via `diag_kws={'bins':...}`. THese parameters are passed to `sns.histplot`